# Changing all elements in a list to floats

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am opening a text file and appending the index[1] of it to a list, with the output being ['18.0', '15', '8.50', '10.50']. My desired output is [18, 15, 8.5, 10.5].

```
file = open(file, "r")
sheet = sheet = [line.strip() for line in theFile]
del sheet[0]
sheet.sort()
for i in sheet:
    lines = (i.split(','))
    list.append(lines[1])
```

Comment: `list.append(float(lines[1]))` just typecast it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest fix is to parse the floating point values as you append them to the list:

```
list.append(float(lines[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` solves your problem pretty easily.

```
newList = list(map(float, myList))
```

The `map` function will apply a function (in this case, `float`) to every value in a list. It returns a `map` object, which we need to convert to a list. That's what `list()` at the beginning of the line does.

So, in your case, it should be something like:

```
lines = list(map(float, lines))
```

which will convert all ints in the list `lines` to floats.